# Cannot find workflow definition even though I register it to worker

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, cadence, uber-cadence

I'm registering two workflows to my Cadence worker based on Spring Boot. However, even though I successfully register all my workflows and start the worker, I'm only able to use one workflow. Here is a code snippet.

```
@Configuration
public class CadenceAutoConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public WorkflowClient workflowClient() {
    return WorkflowClient.newInstance(
        new WorkflowServiceTChannel(ClientOptions.defaultInstance()),
        WorkflowClientOptions.newBuilder().setDomain(DOMAIN).build());
  }

  @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
  public void startWorker(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Starting workers");
    ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
    WorkflowClient workflowClient = context.getBean(WorkflowClient.class);
    WorkerFactory factory = WorkerFactory.newInstance(workflowClient);
    Worker worker = factory.newWorker(TASK_LIST);

    worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(WorkflowA.class);
    worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(WorkflowB.class);
    worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(WorkflowC.class);
    factory.start();
  }
}
```

I'm only able to use `WorkflowC`. When I try to invoke `WorkflowA` and `WorkflowB`, I got `workflow definition not found error`. Wonder how to fix the issue?

Tried to restart the worker and Cadence server but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the `worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes`. This method takes a varag as an input argument and every time this method is called, it will override the previous calls. In this example, the worker will only have `WorkflowC` registered because the first two calls are overridden.

The correct way to register the implementation class is passing all classes into this method by doing something like

```
worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(WorkflowC.class, WorkflowB.class, WorkflowC.class);
```

This will make sure all workflow classes are loaded to the worker at once.